# In Objective-C with ARC, what does compiler do when I define a block?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, block, heap-memory, stack-memory

The code:

```
__block int x = 0;
int *pointerToX = &x;
NSLog(@"x's location is on the stack: %p", &x);    //stack
int (^block)() = ^{
    x += 1;
    return x;
};
NSLog(@"x's location is on the %@: %p", (&x == pointerToX ? @"stack" : @"heap"), &x);  
block();
NSLog(@"x's location is on the %@: %p", (&x == pointerToX ? @"stack" : @"heap"), &x);   
block = [block copy];    
NSLog(@"x's location is on the %@: %p", (&x == pointerToX ? @"stack" : @"heap"), &x);
```

in non-arc

x's location is on the stack: `0xbfffdba0`

x's location is on the stack: `0xbfffdba0`

x's location is on the stack: `0xbfffdba0`

x's location is on the heap: `0x7195860`

in arc:

x's location is on the stack: `0xbfffdb70`

x's location is on the stack: `0xbfffdb70`

x's location is on the stack: `0xbfffdb70`

x's location is on the heap: `0x7195860`

why get difference output in arc and non-arc ?

Comment: The only difference is the memory address on the stack which can vary from run to run

Comment: This looks very similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15082265/why-is-a-block-variable-is-moved-to-the-heap-before-the-block-is-copied.

Comment: @MartinR  it is the same. I got the answer by @ Nikolai Ruhe .

Comment: @gelosie: there doesn't look to be any difference in the output you posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See ARC's [documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#blocks):

> [...] whenever these semantics call for retaining a value of block-pointer type, it has the effect of a Block_copy [...]