# iOS >> Blocks >> Changing Values of Variables External to the Block

Tags: ios, objective-c, block, variable-assignment, objective-c-blocks

I'm familiar with the `__block` statement that makes the variable 'assignable' within a Block.
But I see that when using some of Objective-C features that uses Blocks as Arguments in Methods, some variables are assignable, even if they are not declared with this `__block` statement.

Here are 2 codes for example:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^
     {
         self.animatedView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
         self.animatedView.center = CGPointMake(100, 100);
     }];
```

(animatedView is a simple UIView connected with an IBOutlet).

```
    int myInt = 10;
    NSMutableString* mString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Mutable Hello"];
    NSString* imString = @"Imutable Hello";

    void (^myBlock)(void) = ^
    {
        [mString appendString:@" Block"]; //working
        imString = @"Imutable Hello Block"; //error
        myInt = 11; //error
    };
```

My question is: **How come I can assign values to the UIView instance properties?**

I'm not addressing an Object and changing it, like my mString.

I would expect the 'center' property to behave like my myInt, as it's a C struct accessed directly, and not a pointer to an object.

I would expect 'backgroundColor' to behave like my imString, as it's a pointer to an object which is assigned with a new object, isn't it?

I couldn't find a satisfying explanation in the documentation... I would appreciate if anyone can provide one, or address me to one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the difference between assignment and usage. Usage being method calls. You are entirely permitted to call methods on an instance (`[mString appendString:@" Block"]; //working`) but you can't assign (`imString = @"Imutable Hello Block"; //error`) without tagging the variables to tell the compiler that it should enable it.

This code:

```
self.animatedView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

is still not really an assignment, it's a 'hidden' method call. Dot notation is never an assignment, it's syntactic sugar for method calls. It actually translates to:

```
[[self animatedView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

The difference between assigning to local variables and to variables inside an object is the location in memory that they reside at. Basically, will they exist for long enough to be useful. It's the difference between data on the stack and on the heap.

Comment: So the fact that 'BOOL hidden' or 'CGPoint center' hold ivars behind them doesn't make any difference? Does that mean that since they are Properties (accessed via a Setter method) changes the way they are allocated in memory? I also tried it with an ivar declared in my class (and not a local variable in the method), and it worked as well - and it doesn't go through any method.

Comment: The method is a side effect (for want of a better term). The difference is the memory location. Local variables are created on the stack, so unless you tell the compiler to copy them to the heap they are not accessible. The compiler also uses a number of 'tricks' when making data available inside the block (and the route taken is different between pointers and primitives). It's an in-depth subject, take a read of this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15082265/why-is-a-block-variable-is-moved-to-the-heap-before-the-block-is-copied

Comment: @wain You shouldn't mix in the effect of possible optimizations of the compiler - that only causes confusion. What actually matters is _what_ variable outside the block scope is _captured_ and that "capturing" implies the creation of a _const qualified_ copy of the original variable within the block's scope. With ARC enabled and for captured variables which are retainable objects, a "copy" also implies a retain/release.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper: "With ARC enabled and for captured variables which are retainable objects, a "copy" also implies a retain/release." Even without ARC, for captured variables of object pointer type, it also implies retain/release. But retain/release is when the block is copied, not when it is created.

Comment: @OhadRegev: "Property" means "getter/setter method pair". It doesn't mean anything else. How the getter/setter methods are implemented internally are an implementation detail that you cannot care about.

Comment: @OhadRegev: "I also tried it with an ivar declared in my class" Yes, ivar access is also a "read". Ivar can only be accessed through `self` or some other object pointer, i.e. `someObjPointer->myIvar`. When `myIvar` is specified by itself, it means `self->myIvar`. So you are always reading some object pointer when you are reading or writing to an ivar.

Comment: @newacct In fact, if ARC is enabled and when the variables are captured, they are "const copied", which for retainable pointer means, that they are retained (and released _after_ the block has been executed). If the block will be copied, regardless of ARC enabled, Objective-C pointers will be retained (and released when the block gets deallocated). However, the retain/release which is performed in ARC when a retainable pointer is captured will be usually elided as an effect of the optimization. ;)

Answer (score 3):

To allow a variable to be changed within a block, you use the _*block storage type modifier—see “The* _block Storage Type.”

```
__block NSString* imString = @"Imutable Hello";
```

Reference by [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW2)

The following rules apply to variables used within a block:

1. Global variables are accessible, including static variables that exist within the enclosing lexical scope.
2. Parameters passed to the block are accessible (just like parameters to a function).
   Stack (non-static) variables local to the enclosing lexical scope are captured as const variables.
3. Their values are taken at the point of the block expression within the program. In nested blocks, the value is captured from the nearest enclosing scope.
4. Variables local to the enclosing lexical scope declared with the __block storage modifier are provided by reference and so are mutable.
5. Any changes are reflected in the enclosing lexical scope, including any other blocks defined within the same enclosing lexical scope. These are discussed in more detail in “The __block Storage Type.”
6. Local variables declared within the lexical scope of the block, which behave exactly like local variables in a function.
7. Each invocation of the block provides a new copy of that variable. These variables can in turn be used as const or by-reference variables in blocks enclosed within the block.

Comment: You forgot to mention that this is a verbatim copy from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW2. - It would be more helpful to explain how this applies to the particular question.

Comment: I read this document... And still, it doesn't answer my question. Which of these rules makes the UIView properties, which are not defined with __block, accessible for assignment within the Animation Block. How come my primitive variables are not assignable and UIView's primitive properties are; How come I cannot assign new Object to a pointer, unless I use the __block at declaration, and UIView properties can.

Answer (score 3):

In your first example the block "captures" the variable *self* - which is a pointer to a retainable object. You don't modify *self* itself in your example when you write:

```
self.someProperty = someValue;
```

*self*'s value still remains the same - that is, it still points to the same object.

You would modify *self* for example if you write:

```
self = nil;
```

Comment: OK... This answer actually leads somewhere... So the fact I pass an Object to the Block makes its Properties assignable? I tested it by adding an int property and also an int ivar - with NO __block - to my class, and I saw I can assign them with a new value within the block. Which principle / rule makes the Properties / ivars assignable within a block? While local variables within the method where the Block is defined are not?

Comment: @OhadRegev The fact that you can _invoke a method_ is that the receiver's pointer (here _self_)  won't be changed as an effect of invoking a method (which assigning a property actually is all about). Note _self_ is a pointer, and it's value might be something like `self equals 0xabcd1230` _before_ invoking a method, and after invoking the method it's still the same: `self equals 0xabcd1230`.

Comment: @OhadRegev The fact that captured variables (here the pointer _self_ whose value is 0xabcd1230) are _const_ is simply a _common convention_ when dealing with blocks or lambdas. They _could_ have been also modifiable.